# How do you measure a React Native's app performance while in background?

Tags: ios, react-native, query-optimization, performance-testing

## Batter drain issue while the app is in the background

I've encountered this nasty situation with my work react native app, it drains up to 100% of the user's device battery in a day and not quite sure why.

The app, on newer devices, stays in the background for a long time (older devices don't have the memory and suspend it sooner). Trying to investigate the source of the issue but don't know where to start.

#### UPDATED

Seems the culprit was [`react-native-video`](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2118#issuecomment-1306683866), the `pictureInPicture` is unreliable and according to their docs

> This function corresponds to the completion handler in Apple's restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStop. IMPORTANT: This function must be called after onRestoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStop is called.

If `pictureInPicture` is unreliably set then the `onRestoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStop` can't reliably be called. Disabling `pictureInPicture` has seemingly stopped the battery drain we've been experiencing.

Comment: I assume that your app is running services in the background; could you kindly let me know how many and which services are running?

Comment: You have tagged both Android and iOS. The solutions will be different. For iOS you can use https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MonitorEnergyWithInstruments.html

Comment: @ManishAhire updated question with the culprit